# Set body size in CSS?

Tags: css

I just created a lockscreen theme for my iPhone. It works, but for some reason I cannot remove the black background space of the body, i.e. resize the body along the right and bottom edge of the lockscreen.

I created a short slideshow so you get the.. indeed.

Here's the relevant HTML and complete CSS code. Note that I added many unnecessary '0px' properties just to see if they'd make a difference:

```
<body>
<div id="background">
<img src="LockBackground.jpg" width="320" height="480">
</div>

<div id="labels">
    <div id="clock">//e.g. 6:12 AM
    </div>
    <div id="day">//e.g. Sunday
    </div>
    <div id="date">//e.g. 5 Aug
    </div>
</div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
    *{ margin: 0px; padding: 0px; border: 0px; }
    body  { background-color: #000; border: 0px; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; position: absolute; font-family: Helvetica Neue; font-size: 50px; color: #fff; width: 320px; }
    img { border: 0px; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 320px; z-index: 0; }
    #labels { position: absolute; width: 290px; top: 50%; margin: -0.7em 0 0 30px; }
    #day { line-height: 0.8; }
    #date { position: absolute; margin-top: 18px; line-height: 0.6; }
```

Comment: It's hard to see exactly what is out of place without knowing what it should look like

Comment: Is LockBackground.jpg the picture of the city?

Comment: also, I jst noticed you haven't got any css hooked up to the "background" div

Comment: The picture of the city is the Lockbackground.jpg and black parts aren't supposed to be there. No, I haven't assigned the background div...

Comment: Why have you set body to position:absolute? I don't see a reason for that. Try removing this, and adding incremental z-indexes on img and .labels Also: you're setting z-index on img without positioning won't work, z-index is only for postioned elements...

Comment: Yeah, the absolute position was not intentional. So I changed that back and added z-indexes. Unfortunately it doesn't help.. If you think about it, the body background is black and it only 'stucks out' to the bottom and left. So it must be some sort of width/height issue of the body right?

Comment: can you update your code in your question to the current state? or even better - post your code in a jsfiddle.com?

Comment: Ok, here it is: http://jsfiddle.net/KeyMs92/7fuAN/ (I've removed the properties that had no visible effect.)

Comment: Have you managed to look into it? Thanks.

Comment: Make sure that you're also addressing the CSS for the `html` element as well.

Answer (score 1):

Surely you just need `body {width:100%; height:100%;}`.

It may be more complex than this, but I can't think why it would be.

You could also try `img {width:100%; height:100%;}`.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I noticed that the problem is that the wrong screen size is detected, so when I set the img and body to 100% it will stretch the lockscreen beyond the edges of the screen. Do you know how to solve this?

Comment: You could either: 1. Trial and error. Keep adjusting the %age till it is perfect. 2. Use Javascript to set the size. This is probably the best option if you are going to use it on anything apart from you're iPhone. If you are only using that one iPhone, option 1 will make it load faster, and be smoother. If you chose 2, I can build that code if you like, just ask.